# How to Get a Similar color as LightSteelBlue3 in El Capitan?

Tags: color, latex

I see many LaTeX threads with the font, etc [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline).
I am interested in the similar colors as LightSteelBlue3 in OS X that are by default, because I cannot find the color in Homebrew and not by default.

In *TeX Live Utility*, I find the packages *xcolor*, *colortbl* and *caption* as *installed*.

---

How can you get a similar color as LightSteelBlue3 in El Capitan?

Comment: If you already have the packages installed, what exactly is your problem in using them?

Comment: @patrix It says there is no such packages so they are not found for some reason.

Comment: Please update your question then (Terminal output etc.), we can't see your screen :-) Might also help to know whether other packages installed via TLU work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196808/8713). Just install `xcolor` (and any other missing packages) via TeX Live Utility (or manually) and run `latex` as usual.

Comment: I accept this answer because I had some problems with the packages. The complication was caused by `Beamer` documentclass which confused me about the origin of the problem. A new thread about it here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302851/13173 in TeX Stackexchange.